# Why can I not pass a captured token to a nested macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Multiple examples I've seen suggest that this should be possible, but it is apparently not:

`lib.rs`:

```
#![feature(trace_macros)]

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! inner_macro (
    (f32) => {"float"};
);

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! outer_macro {
    ($T:ty) => {
        inner_macro!($T)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test_nested() {
        trace_macros!(true);
        s1: String = String::from(outer_macro!(f32));
        s2: String = String::from(inner_macro!(f32));
        trace_macros!(false);
    }
}
```

Running `cargo test` gives the following output:

```
error: no rules expected the token `f32`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:22
   |
4  | / macro_rules! inner_macro (
5  | |     (f32) => {"float"};
6  | | );
   | |__- when calling this macro
...
11 |           inner_macro!($T)
   |                        ^^ no rules expected the token `f32`
...
21 |           s1: String = String::from(outer_macro!(f32));
   |                                     ----------------- in this macro invocation
```

This is confusing, because there certainly appears to be a rule expecting the token `f32`.

There are also notes from the expansion trace of the two macros. The first one does not work:

```
= note: expanding `outer_macro! { f32 }`
= note: to `inner_macro ! ( f32 )`
= note: expanding `inner_macro! { f32 }`
```

while the second one does:

```
= note: expanding `inner_macro! { f32 }`
= note: to `"float"`
```

**Why does the first expansion of `inner_macro!` fail, while the exact same expansion succeeds when it is not nested inside another macro?**

Edit: if we perform the substitution manually, it works and gives the expected output:

```
macro_rules! unknown {
    ($T:ty) => {
        inner_macro!(f32)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After [some more reading](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-captures-and-expansion-redux.html), it turns out this is an instance of a typical stumbling block. After being captured the first time, `$T` takes the value of an *AST Node*. Substituting `$T` will not emplace a token, it will emplace that AST Node. So what I expected to be something like this:

```
inner_macro!(`f32` [token])
```

was actually

```
inner_macro!(<Type>f32</Type>)
```

Unfortunately for users, the two invocations both get stringified the same way, to `inner_macro! ( f32 )`.

The correct way to do this is to capture the token-to-be-substituted as a "token tree":

```
macro_rules! unknown {
    ($T:tt) => {
        inner_macro!($T)
    }
}
```